# How to use custom HistoryRepository in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I would like to know what is the best way to inject custom implementation of `IHistoryRepository`during database migrations.

Will this

```
OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IHistoryRepository, MyRepository>();
}
```

work with ASP.NET Core or should I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an email back from Brice Lambson

If all you want to do is change the name (or schema), there is a simple way to do that:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
    "MyConnectionString",
    x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("MyHistoryTable", "mySchema"));
```

To replace the IHistoryRepository service in EF Core 1.1, here is some code.

```
optionsBuilder
    .UseSqlServer("MyConnectionString")
    .ReplaceService<SqlServerHistoryRepository, MyHistoryRepository>();
```

The reason you replace the provider-specific type is because IHistoryRepository is resolved per-provider using DatabaseProviderServices and friends. See SqlServerDatabaseProviderServices for the relevant line of code.